# Using Diff() and Lag () functions for computing Month-on-Month Inflation in R

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality

Assuming my data looks like this;

```
+--------+----------+
| Month  | WPI_All  |
+--------+----------+
| Jul-15 | 177.5    |
| Jun-15 | 178.6    |
| May-15 | 178      |
| Apr-15 | 176.4    |
| Mar-15 | 176.1    |
| Feb-15 | 175.6    |
| Jan-15 | 177.3    |
| Dec-14 | 178.7    |
| Nov-14 | 181.2    |
| Oct-14 | 183.7    |
| Sep-14 | 185      |
| Aug-14 | 185.9    |
| Jul-14 | 185      |
| Jun-14 | 183      |
| May-14 | 182      |
| Apr-14 | 180.8    |
+--------+----------+
```

I would like to know how to use the `diff()` or the `lag()` functions to get the Month-On-Month inflation values? Where $$MoM_{INF} = ((P_{t}- P_{t-12}/P_{t-12})*100)$$

Is there a specific method to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `head` and `tail` to compute the inflation.

```
n <- 12

mydf[-seq(n), "infl"] <- (tail(mydf$WPI_All, -n) - head(mydf$WPI_All, -n)) / 
                            head(mydf$WPI_All, -n) * 100
```

Here, `mydf` is the name of your data frame.

The result:

```
    Month WPI_All     infl
1  Jul-15   177.5       NA
2  Jun-15   178.6       NA
3  May-15   178.0       NA
4  Apr-15   176.4       NA
5  Mar-15   176.1       NA
6  Feb-15   175.6       NA
7  Jan-15   177.3       NA
8  Dec-14   178.7       NA
9  Nov-14   181.2       NA
10 Oct-14   183.7       NA
11 Sep-14   185.0       NA
12 Aug-14   185.9       NA
13 Jul-14   185.0 4.225352
14 Jun-14   183.0 2.463606
15 May-14   182.0 2.247191
16 Apr-14   180.8 2.494331
```

Comment: This is great, works prefectly! But I used the following `diff(WPI_All$WPI_All, lag=12)` and then convert it into a time series argument, the values seem to be differing quite a bit. I'm not sure how the `diff()` or the `lag()` function seems to work, is there anyplace except the actual manual where I could read about it? Thank you very much for the help!